# Read OpenCV Mat 16bit to QImage 8bit Greyscale

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, bit, converters

### What i want to do

1. **File**: TIFF, 2 Pages, Greyscale, 16bit
2. **OpenCV**: 2x Mat, Greyscale, 16bit (CV_16UC1)
3. **Qt**: 2x QImage, Greyscale, 8bit (Format_Greyscale8)

I want to read a 16bit Tiff and then convert it to show it as 8bit.

### Reading

```
void ImgProc::Load_Image_2xTiff_16bit_G(Mat *Mat_A_in, Mat *Mat_B_in, string file_name)
{  
    vector<Mat> vec_Mat;
    vec_Mat.reserve(2);

    imreadmulti(file_name, vec_Mat);

    *Mat_A_in = vec_Mat[0];
    *Mat_B_in = vec_Mat[1];
}
```

### Conversion

```
void ImgProc::Convert_Mat16_2_QIm8(QImage *QIm_Out, Mat *Mat_In, double scale_factor)
{
    unsigned int rows = Mat_In->rows;
    unsigned int cols = Mat_In->cols;
    *QIm_Out = QImage(cols, rows, QImage::Format_Grayscale8);
    unsigned char* line_QIm;

    if (!Mat_In->data)
        return;

    for(unsigned int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
    {
        line_QIm = QIm_Out->scanLine(y);
        for(unsigned int x = 0; x < cols; x++)
        {
            line_QIm[x] = (unsigned char)(Mat_In->at<ushort>(y, x) * scale_factor);
        }
    }
}
```

### Problem

When i use `Mat_In->at<ushort>(y, x)` (read 16bits) it crashes with `abort() has been called`. Same happens if i use `<short>` instead.

When i use `Mat_In->at<uchar>(y, x)` (read 8bits) it works, but cuts off information without scaling. That shows up as "black holes" in the brighter areas of the image, probably an overflow effect.

I think i should mention, that the camera that took the images only uses 14bit depth.

Comment: What is the actual [type of the elements](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aa6477efc7399fbe742418250ccf99a4b) of `Mat_In`? | Why not use [`cv::Mat::convertTo`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a3f356665bb0ca452e7d7723ccac9a810) (and then just work with the entire raw buffer, rather than looping over it pixel by pixel).

Comment: `Mat_In.type();` returns `0`.
I tried to use `cv::Mat::convertTo` but failed, so i tried this way. I also like, that i exactly know what happens there and can manipulate any time i want to.

Comment: Type of `0` corresponds to `CV_8U`, meaning the image is already 8bit. That would explain the crash (I'd expect once it gets though half the rows). Can you provide a sample image that produces this issue?

Comment: show how you read the image file. OpenCV reads as 8UC3 type by default

Comment: @Micka My read-method is shown above. Good hint, thanks. I'll try to figure out how to read it as 16bit.

Comment: Jhon_Sharp1318s Answer worked when i added `cv::IMREAD_ANYDEPTH|cv::IMREAD_ANYCOLOR` as flags to `imreadmulti`, so Dan Masek your thought was correct, thanks.

Comment: @kemedil ah ok, I didn't know the `imreadmulti` function yet and thought it was some user function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same type kind of issue.
The following code is the solution I used to fix that case.

```
   #include <opencv2/core.hpp>
   #include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
   #include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

   #include <QImage>

    int main(void)
    {

      //Read the 16 bit per pixel image.
      cv::Mat I = cv::imread('16BitsPerPixelImage.tiff',cv::IMREAD_ANYDEPTH|cv::IMREAD_ANYCOLOR);

     //Convert from 16 bit per pixel to 8 bit per pixel using a min max normalization and store it a 8 bit per pixel.
     cv::normalize(I,I,0.,255.,cv::NORM_MINMAX,CV_8U);

    // Then actualy the easiest way to convert it to a QImage is to save a temporary file and open it using QT functions.
    // PNG use a compression without loss algorithm.
      cv::imwrite("/tmp/convert16to8.png",I);

      QImage QI;

      QI.load("/tmp/convert16to8.png");

      return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: Adding `cv::IMREAD_ANYDEPTH|cv::IMREAD_ANYCOLOR` as flags for `imreadmulti` solved the problem, the rest of my code worked as it is. Thank you very much! Now i can start doing the cool stuff.